# AVR ATMega 2560 USB driver error

Tags: windows, avr, atmega, atmel, atmelstudio

I have an issue while installing drivers for the ATMega 2560. I downloaded the drivers from the ATMEL website, no issues during installation, but once small window pops up it gives me an error that the drivers are not compatible with x64 operating systems, although a lot of my colleagues are using x64. If you need I can take a snip of the error message.

P.S. Forgot to mention I`m using x64 Windows 8.1, with the latest updates installed and Atmel Studio 6.2.1153

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently and many of the driver links on the Atmel and other sites are for old versions of the driver. If you install the [Atmel Software Framework](http://www.atmel.com/tools/avrsoftwareframework.aspx) you'll find signed drivers in a location similar to the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel USB Drivers\inf\atmel_devices_cdc\atmel_devices_cdc.inf
C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel USB Drivers\inf\atmel_devices_cdc\atmelinf.cat
```

Supported Windows versions are listed as Windows 2000, XP, Vista, 7 and 8 (x32 and x64) and I've confirmed it works fine on Windows 8.1 x64 as well. I've assumed you're using a CDC class driver but there are also updated drivers for the DFU bootloader if that's what you're after.